# javascript save dynamic object in someplace for resuse byother methods later on!

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic, object

i want to save javascript object in a place, so if selected row is getting trigger, i can use that row object again by different methods.

maybe saving it in input hidden field can work? but not sure.. how would you do it?

im trying to do following, but that dont work, obviously my code is wrong, but i want to show you, so you can maybe tell proper way to do it.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {

        var video = {title: 'this is title', time: '2:32:20'}
        $('.arr').val(video);

        $('.show').click(function() {
            console.log($('.arr').val());
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="arr" class="arr" value="" />
<input type="button" class="show" value="Show" />
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you need, exactly? What kind of information, attached to what kind of presentation?

Comment: basically im getting object for each row from json server and i want to save that object for later use, like on delete or rename or anything.. so i want to save that each pulled object and referenced it to that row and pull it back, if need to use that object again.

btw object would contain list of values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQuery has support for element data (see http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data). This allows you to set data in a "known" spot, like the document itself to be retrieved later.

```
$(document).data('foo','my data');
```

which can be retrieved as:

```
$(document).data('foo') // 'my data'
```

You are not limited to string values, objects can also be stored.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand right, you can save these objects you got from the "json server" using the jquery `.data()` method. If the object you want to save is in a variable named `myobject` and  you want to save it with a DOM element with id `"someid"`

```
$('#someid').data('mydata', myobject);
```

saves the data. To retrieve:

```
var thedata = $('#someid').data('mydata');
```

Comment: i voted you and him, but you both are right.. sence he answered first, so ill go with him. but thank you :)

Comment: It's kind of a bummer there is no way to merge answers that are the same and share points or something... might be a good new feature.