# create object with javascript on load for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Is it possible with javascript/jQuery to create objects on page load (or (document).ready) and then later use them, for example on keyup on an input.
If so, how?

Comment: `var obj = {};` in global scope or any scope shared by the functions you want to use the object in. Then just access it with `obj` inside the functions. All the basic rules of variables and scope apply.

Comment: window.obj = {}; will create a global obj object from any scope and can be accessed in any scope.

Comment: you can also check jquery data() apis. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975095/javascript-save-dynamic-object-in-someplace-for-resuse-byother-methods-later-on for a better answer

Comment: I get the impression the OP doesn't actually want a JS object but rather Html elements (as in pre-loading or at least pre-preparing)? I may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all code in `$(document).ready{all code here}` then your variables won't go out of scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someObject={};
  $("selector").click(function(e){
    console.log(someObject);
  });
});
```

If you're using onclick in html then I'd advice you to change that and move all JS code to JS file or `<script>` block (not in your html).

Instead of putting many variables on global scope you can namespace it (if you can't put all code in $(document).ready).

```
var myApplication = myApplication || {};//if myApplication doesn't exist then create it
myApplication.someObject = {};
```

Then even if your JS is spread over several files you can still maintain one myApplication object.

As gp mentioned; you can use data to add data to html elements:

```
$("#somebutton").on("click",function(e){
  $(this).data("someObject",{});// you can use e.target instead of this as well
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below find a example usage.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    TODO write content
    <div id="MytextID">My text </div>
    <input type="text" id="inputId" name="name">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = $('#MytextID');
        $('#inputId').keyup(function(){
            alert(x.text());
        })
    })

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```